# Android: Black screen but touch events working

Tags: android, screen, touch-event

I notice a strange behavior for my app.

After a while while the app is Foreground or background when it tries to go to the next activity it shows a black screen but the touch events works. There is no crash and the strangest thing is that if he presses in the black screen and navigates to the next activity everything is ok BUT again from there if he goes further then again he has a black screen

This happes regardless version or device.

I am quite sure that has to do with memory and there is not much to do but if anyone had a similar behavior please comment.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace? code?

Comment: There is nothing to do with the code i think since there is no error in stacktrace and it happens randomly. I truly seek for a similar case rather a solution. As i said i think this is due to memory but perhaps i am wrong. All activities start normally and there are no heavy graphics